# Why does sorting in redux causes to error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have sorting script in my Redux file:

```
case INVENTORY_FROM_LOW:
  return {
    ...state,
    inventory: state.inventory.sort((a, b) => {
      return (a.price - b.price)
    })
  }
```

And when I'm calling 'INVENTORY_FROM_LOW', I get:
[image: Error image]

Comment: `sort` sorts the array in place and then returns the array. The array in state could be frozen or something. It's not a good idea to call `sort` on a part of the state anyway (it mutates the state). I would start with `state.inventory.slice().sort`.

Comment: @Sulthan thank's a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new array then sort that array.

```
case INVENTORY_FROM_LOW:
   const inventory = [...state.inventory];
   inventory.sort((a, b) => {
      return (a.price - b.price)
    });

return {
    ...state,
    inventory
  };
```

I guess you are having this error because everything in the state is immutable.

Comment: `sort` does return a value. It returns the array.

Comment: @Sulthan actually you are right. But still need to copy the array to avoid the error because of the immutability of the state.

Comment: I know that, I have already written that into a comment. However, using `slice()` would be more efficient.